# jquery change interact with click function

Tags: jquery, click, onchange, interaction

I've a problem: I made a function to make some calculations, based on change function; now I'ld like to be able to modify the content of one of the factors acting on the result of the (one row) calculation using click function; this operation should be done on different rows.

Each function works well on its own, but there's no interaction with the other ones.

The click func:

```
$("#calc").click(function() {
        var totale = parseFloat($("#subtot1b").val());
        var kgr = parseFloat($("#q1").val());

        var pu = totale / kgr;
        $("#pu1").val(parseFloat(totale / kgr).toFixed(5));
    });
```

The change func:

```
$('#q1,#pu1,#tax1,#tax2,#q2,#pu2').change(function() {
//do something});
```

There's some tip I can Use?

Many Thanks to All.

Best Wishes.

My example is shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/skipperit/4DXPV/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to recal your change function at the end of the click function.

Declare your function:

```
function myChangeFunction() {
   //do something;
   }
```

The `click` behavior:

```
$("#calc").click(function() {
    var totale = parseFloat($("#subtot1b").val());
    var kgr = parseFloat($("#q1").val());

    var pu = totale / kgr;
    $("#pu1").val(parseFloat(totale / kgr).toFixed(5));

    myChangeFunction();
});
```

The `change` behavior:

```
$('#q1,#pu1,#tax1,#tax2,#q2,#pu2').change(
   myChangeFunction();
);
```

Comment: tks Nienn for super quick tip ;)